# setup c# windows Application on windows startup

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

I am writing a windows application that wish to create different dialog (Yes/No types) etc. But I want to run this application every time whenever windows startup.But once this application is installed next time when user login on windows that will start automatically in background process.My (ScreenDialog.exe)  found in C:\ directory and app require administrator permission for c directory usage. 
But Code Which I am using not working.

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
key.SetValue("ScreenDialog", "C:\\ScreenDialog.exe");
```

Comment: What exactly does not work? Does the key not get set? Does the program not start? Does it crash? If so, what does the exception say?

Comment: I think key not get set,I try to start by restarting windows or by shutting down but it's not working.

Comment: You think? Check the registry and see... And what version of Windows?

Comment: windows 8.0 64 bit version.

Comment: I have to start it on every type of windows So What should I do ? That still not working

Comment: What about throwing it into `shell:startup` folder? Just `Win+R` and type in `shell:startup` - should run on Windows startup always for CURRUSR.

Comment: No m_wilczynski because I want to do it programmatically.I don't want to assign hard work to my client for dragging.

Comment: for windows 7 and windows 8 this is used m_wilczynski then I use to move folder of exe programmatically

Answer (score 1):

I use own class, first check it as follows:

- Windows Version
- Run As Admin Programs

On the basis of the above *options* you can find the desired folder in the **registry*, and if it's not stored in the registry or an error occurred, then you must create a **shortcut** of the program in the windows startup folder.

My class Codes:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.Principal;
using Microsoft.Win32;

public static class ComponentController
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Is application running as administrator?
    /// </summary>
    public static Boolean IsAdmin()
    {
        WindowsIdentity identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();

        if (identity != null)
            return (new WindowsPrincipal(identity)).IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);

        return false;
    }

    public static Boolean IsWindowsVistaOrHigher()
    {
        OperatingSystem os = Environment.OSVersion;
        return ((os.Platform == PlatformID.Win32NT) && (os.Version.Major >= 6));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add executable file of this app to registry startup path:
    /// 'LocalMachine\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run'
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="targetEveryone">Run as administrator</param>
    public static void AddToStartup(Boolean targetEveryone)
    {
        try
        {
            using (RegistryKey main = (targetEveryone & IsAdmin() ? Registry.LocalMachine : Registry.CurrentUser))
            {
                using (RegistryKey key = main.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true))
                {
                    String fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Application.ExecutablePath);

                    if (key.GetValue(fileName) == null)
                        key.SetValue(fileName, Application.ExecutablePath);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // report exception ...

            //
            // Copy Shortcut To CommonStartUp or StartUp
            //
            try
            {
                Environment.SpecialFolder folder = ((targetEveryone && IsWindowsVistaOrHigher()) ? Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonStartup : Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup);
                String fileDestination = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(folder), Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Application.ExecutablePath)) + ".lnk";

                if (!File.Exists(fileDestination))
                    Shortcut.Create(fileDestination, Application.ExecutablePath, null, null, "description...", null, null);
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                // report exception ...
            }
        }
    }


    public class Shortcut
    {
        private static Type m_type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("WScript.Shell");
        private static object m_shell = Activator.CreateInstance(m_type);

        [ComImport, TypeLibType((short)0x1040), Guid("F935DC23-1CF0-11D0-ADB9-00C04FD58A0B")]
        private interface IWshShortcut
        {
            [DispId(0)]
            string FullName { [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] [DispId(0)] get; }

            [DispId(0x3e8)]
            string Arguments { [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] [DispId(0x3e8)] get; [param: In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] [DispId(0x3e8)] set; }

            [DispId(0x3e9)]
            string Description { [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] [DispId(0x3e9)] get; [param: In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] [DispId(0x3e9)] set; }

            [DispId(0x3ea)]
            string Hotkey { [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] [DispId(0x3ea)] get; [param: In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] [DispId(0x3ea)] set; }

            [DispId(0x3eb)]
            string IconLocation { [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] [DispId(0x3eb)] get; [param: In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] [DispId(0x3eb)] set; }

            [DispId(0x3ec)]
            string RelativePath { [param: In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] [DispId(0x3ec)] set; }

            [DispId(0x3ed)]
            string TargetPath { [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] [DispId(0x3ed)] get; [param: In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] [DispId(0x3ed)] set; }

            [DispId(0x3ee)]
            int WindowStyle { [DispId(0x3ee)] get; [param: In] [DispId(0x3ee)] set; }

            [DispId(0x3ef)]
            string WorkingDirectory { [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] [DispId(0x3ef)] get; [param: In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] [DispId(0x3ef)] set; }

            [TypeLibFunc((short)0x40), DispId(0x7d0)]
            void Load([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string PathLink);

            [DispId(0x7d1)]
            void Save();
        }

        public static void Create(string fileName, string targetPath, string arguments, string workingDirectory, string description, string hotkey, string iconPath)
        {
            IWshShortcut shortcut = (IWshShortcut)m_type.InvokeMember("CreateShortcut", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, m_shell, new object[] { fileName });

            shortcut.Description = description;
            shortcut.TargetPath = targetPath;
            shortcut.WorkingDirectory = string.IsNullOrEmpty(workingDirectory) ? targetPath : workingDirectory;
            shortcut.Arguments = arguments;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(hotkey)) shortcut.Hotkey = hotkey;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(iconPath)) shortcut.IconLocation = iconPath;
            else shortcut.IconLocation = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(targetPath).Location.Replace('\\', '/');

            shortcut.Save();
        }
    }
}
```